# How to transform a picture in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, image

I want to transform a picture into a square matrix with `NxN` dimension. The elements of the matrix are represented by 0 (red color) or 1 (blue color), from the figure below.

[image]

```
n = 128; (*dimension of matrix*)
f[i_, j_] := (*rule to generated the tube*)
s = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}]; (*matrix*)
MatrixForm[s];
```

I tried to implement several routines for `f[i_,j_]`, but none of them worked. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The ImageData function may be helpful here.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have the photo already you could just directly convert this into a numeric matrix by copying the image into the "image" placeholder using the code below:

```
n = 128;
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQkvZ.png"];
image = ImageResize[image, {n,n}];
data = ImageData[ChanVeseBinarize[image]];
MatrixPlot[data]
MatrixPlot[1 - data]
```

[image]
[image]

This will create a matrix of 1's and 0's where the 0's represent the red pixels and the 1's represent the blue pixels.

Comment: I find that `ChanVeseBinarize[]` does a good job of cleaning up the artifacts in the right part of the OP's image.

Comment: Hi @J.M., thanks for the great work.  I noticed that in your code, 1's. represents the red pixel and 0's represents the blue pixel. Could you tell me how to change the ordering? Also, how to generate a 128x128 matrix? In other words, how to control the matrix dimension? The matrix generated above has dimension 127x126

Comment: To switch the 1's and 0's you could use: `swappedData = data /. {1 -> 0, 0 -> 1}`

Comment: `1 - data` should also work for making the swap @SAC wanted.

Comment: @SAC You can add the line `image = ImageResize[image, {n, n}];` inbetween and this will give an output matrix that is n by n. `ImageResize` migh stretch your image, look at the documentation of `ImageResize` for ways on how to handle this.

Comment: I added that line as an edit

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion, thank you very much for the suggestion. It was excellent. Thanks for editing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
n = 128;
n2 = n/2;
del = 15;
f[i_, j_] := Which[
  j < n2 && n2 - del < i < n2 + del, 1,
  n2 <= j && -del < j - i < del, 1,
  n2 <= j && n - del < j + i < n + del, 1,
  True, 0
  ]
s = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}];
MatrixForm[s];
MatrixPlot[s]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Colorize...

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQkvZ.png"]
MorphologicalBinarize[image] // Colorize
```

[image]

```
ImageData[MorphologicalBinarize[image]]
```

gives the matrix of 0s and 1s.