# How to obtain a 3D matrix from Graphics3D?

Tags: matrix, graphics3d, conversion, image3d, rasterize

I have a capillary system and I want to convert this into a numeric matrix. My aim is to create a matrix with NxNxN dimensions of 1's and 0's where the 0's represent the capillary and the 1's represent the transparent region into the box (similar to 2d's case [questioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259720/how-to-transform-a-picture-in-a-matrix/259725#259725) and answered).

The capillary was built manually; it is consists of tubes with different diameters/radius

```
(*trunk*)
t0 = {{4, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 2}};
r0 = 0.7;
(*first branches*)
t11 = {{4, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 4}};
t12 = {{4, 4, 2}, {6, 4, 4}};
t13 = {{4, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 4}};
t14 = {{4, 4, 2}, {4, 6, 4}};
r1 = 0.4;
(*first branche's secondary branches*)
t21 = {{3, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 5}};
t22 = {{3, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 5}};
t23 = {{5, 4, 3}, {6, 5, 5}};
t24 = {{5, 4, 3}, {6, 3, 5}};
t25 = {{4, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 5}};
t26 = {{4, 3, 3}, {5, 2, 5}};
t27 = {{4, 5, 3}, {5, 6, 5}};
t28 = {{4, 5, 3}, {3, 6, 5}};
r2 = 0.2;
(*second branches*)
t31 = {{4, 2, 4}, {1, 0, 5}};
t32 = {{4, 2, 4}, {7, 0, 5}};
t33 = {{4, 6, 4}, {1, 8, 5}};
t34 = {{4, 6, 4}, {7, 8, 5}};
t35 = {{2, 4, 4}, {0, 7, 5}};
t36 = {{2, 4, 4}, {0, 1, 5}};
t37 = {{6, 4, 4}, {8, 7, 5}};
t38 = {{6, 4, 4}, {8, 1, 5}};
r3 = 0.3;
(* branches to center*)
t41 = {{4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 6}};
t42 = {{4, 6, 4}, {4, 5, 6}};
t43 = {{2, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 6}};
t44 = {{6, 4, 4}, {5, 4, 6}};
r4 = 0.1;
(*branches to center (vertical)*)
t51 = {{4, 3, 6}, {4, 3, 8}};
t52 = {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 8}};
t53 = {{3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 8}};
t54 = {{5, 4, 6}, {5, 4, 8}};
r5 = 0.1;
(*secondary branches conection*)
t61 = {{3, 2, 5}, {1, 1, 8}};
t62 = {{5, 2, 5}, {7, 1, 8}};
t63 = {{5, 6, 5}, {7, 7, 8}};
t64 = {{3, 6, 5}, {1, 7, 8}};
t65 = {{2, 5, 5}, {1, 7, 8}};
t66 = {{6, 5, 5}, {7, 7, 8}};
t67 = {{6, 3, 5}, {7, 1, 8}};
r6 = 0.1;
```

To generate the tubes with different diameters, I joined the radius to the branches

```
(*trunk*)
J0 = {{{4, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 2}}, r0};(*start and end point*)
(*first branches*)
J11 = {{{4, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 4}}, r1};
J12 = {{{4, 4, 2}, {6, 4, 4}}, r1};
J13 = {{{4, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 4}}, r1};
J14 = {{{4, 4, 2}, {4, 6, 4}}, r1};
(*first branche's secondary branches*)
J21 = {{{3, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 5}}, r2};
J22 = {{{3, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}, r2};
J23 = {{{5, 4, 3}, {6, 5, 5}}, r2};
J24 = {{{5, 4, 3}, {6, 3, 5}}, r2};
J25 = {{{4, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 5}}, r2};
J26 = {{{4, 3, 3}, {5, 2, 5}}, r2};
J27 = {{{4, 5, 3}, {5, 6, 5}}, r2};
J28 = {{{4, 5, 3}, {3, 6, 5}}, r2};
(*second branches*)
J31 = {{{4, 2, 4}, {1, 0, 5}}, r3};
J32 = {{{4, 2, 4}, {7, 0, 5}}, r3};
J33 = {{{4, 6, 4}, {1, 8, 5}}, r3};
J34 = {{{4, 6, 4}, {7, 8, 5}}, r3};
J35 = {{{2, 4, 4}, {0, 7, 5}}, r3};
J36 = {{{2, 4, 4}, {0, 1, 5}}, r3};
J37 = {{{6, 4, 4}, {8, 7, 5}}, r3};
J38 = {{{6, 4, 4}, {8, 1, 5}}, r3};
(* branches to center*)
J41 = {{{4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 6}}, r4};
J42 = {{{4, 6, 4}, {4, 5, 6}}, r4};
J43 = {{{2, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}, r4};
J44 = {{{6, 4, 4}, {5, 4, 6}}, r4};
(*branches to center (vertical)*)
J51 = {{{4, 3, 6}, {4, 3, 8}}, r5};
J52 = {{{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 8}}, r5};
J53 = {{{3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 8}}, r5};
J54 = {{{5, 4, 6}, {5, 4, 8}}, r5};
(*secondary branches conection*)
J61 = {{{3, 2, 5}, {1, 1, 8}}, r6};
J62 = {{{5, 2, 5}, {7, 1, 8}}, r6};
J63 = {{{5, 6, 5}, {7, 7, 8}}, r6};
J64 = {{{3, 6, 5}, {1, 7, 8}}, r6};
J65 = {{{2, 5, 5}, {1, 7, 8}}, r6};
J66 = {{{6, 5, 5}, {7, 7, 8}}, r6};
J67 = {{{6, 3, 5}, {7, 1, 8}}, r6};
J = {J0,J11,J12,J13,J14,J21,J22,J23,J24,J25,J26,J27,J28,J31,J32,J33,J34,J35,J36,J37,J38,J41,J42, J43,J44,J51,J52,J53,J54,J61,J62,J63,J64,J65,J66,J67};

Graphics3D[Tube[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ J]
```

The figure generated by this branching process is

[image]

How to obtain a 3d matrix (with dimension 128x128x128)?

Is it possible to save this image in 3D (pixel)? If yes, so could import it a list of images as a 3D volume:

```
n = 128;
image = Import["image", "Image3D"]
image = ImageResize[image, {n,n,n}];
data = ImageData[MorphologicalBinarize[image]];
MatrixPlot[data]
MatrixPlot[1 - data]
```

Or alternatively, would it be possible some alternative way to get this 3D matrix?

```
n = 128; (*dimension of matrix*)
f[i_, j_, k_] := (*rule to generated the tube*)
s = SparseArray[{{i_, j_, k_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n, n}]; (*matrix*)
MatrixForm[s];
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What format would you want the 3D image exported in? You can likely specify the dimensions of your export to accomplish what you want, depending on your desired file format.

Comment: So then the file format is `"*.tiff"`. Have you tried explicitly exporting your `Graphics3D` in said format, specifying the desired image size/resolution?

Comment: I think exporting 3D to TIFF requires an `Image3D`, not a `Graphics3D`. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179593/58370) question for ways to do that.

Comment: Did you edit this from the original question to a completely different question? I remember this being about how to export your 3D image. Please, do not completely change your question to a new question via editing, instead, ask a completely different and new question by making a new post...

Answer (score 6):

You can apply [`FillingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingTransform.html) directly to the [`Image3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html) produced using [`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html) to fill the hollow tubes:

```
si = Graphics3D[Tube[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ J];
si2 = RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[si]];
si3 = si2 // FillingTransform // Binarize;
Image3DSlices[si3]
```

[image]

Comment: Great work. It was exactly the `FillingTransform` command I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Another way is use `CapsuleShape` instead of `Tube`.

```
reg = Region[RegionUnion[CapsuleShape[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ J]]
ri = RegionImage[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]
result = Image3DSlices[ri]
GraphicsGrid[Partition[result, UpTo[12]]]
```

- `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `Tube` is not a filled 3D-polygon. This is just a pipe.
However, the question about how to obtain the cross-section of a region is a really interesting.
The simplest way is:

```
Rasterize[
 Graphics3D[{
   DiscretizeRegion[
    MeshRegion@
     DiscretizeGraphics[si, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001],
     {{0, 8}, {0,8}, {4.995, 5}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000001]}, 
  ViewPoint -> Above, Boxed -> False],
 ImageSize -> 800,
 RasterSize -> 1920]
```

It gives you:
[image]

As one can see, choosing the third range (z-value range) in `DiscretizeRegion` you can take the position of desired cross-section. But these are still just points not a curve..
Playing with z-range, `RasterSize` and `ImageSize` one can adjust the image quality. Or you can look on this site for a post-processing of raster to make curves.