# Definition of Tube as a Region

Tags: bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 13.0.0 and fixed in 13.0.1** [CASE:4894156]

---

In version 13, `Tube` is a recognized region. E.g., `RegionQ[Tube[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]]` returns `True`. However, it's not clear what the precise definition of the region is. Comparing with a cylinder, suggests that a `Tube` region from a single line segment is the surface of a cylinder, but with hemispherical caps:

```
 Graphics3D[{Style[Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/2],
     Opacity[0.5, Red]], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/2]}]
```

But the area of the tube is not what I expect from that of a cylinder and the caps:

```
Simplify[Area[Tube[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]], h > 0]
```

gives

```
4 \[Pi] (h + r^2)
```

which adds different physical quantities: a length (h) and an area (r^2).

Compare to the surface area of a cylinder:

```
Simplify[SurfaceArea[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]], h > 0]
```

which gives

```
2 \[Pi] r (2 h + r)
```

The difference in areas between `Tube` and `Cylinder` suggests the tube is not the surface of the cylinder with circular ends replaced by hemispheres.

The area of the tube region also differs from discretizing a graphics:

```
With[{reg = Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.5]},
 {Area[reg], SurfaceArea[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[reg]]}
 ]
```

gives different values for the tube region and discretized graphics:

```
{15.708, 9.32718}
```

To find a definition of the `Tube` region, I tried

```
RegionConvert[Tube[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r], "Implicit"]
```

but that does not evaluate. In contrast, `RegionConvert` does work for a cylinder.

Is the difference between `Tube` and `Cylinder` just a problem with the evaluation of `Area`? Or is `Tube` as a region something different than as it appears as a graphics?

Comment: `Tube` is a complex object compare to  `CapsuleShape`. `Volume[CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]]`

Comment: The title: Is "Region" literal or not?

Comment: `4 \[Pi] (h + r^2)` is my new favourite surface area formula, great work Mathematica!

Comment: CapsuleShape, which is a filled-in version of this tube, gives the same surface area: `Simplify[SurfaceArea[CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]], h > 0]` gives `4 \[Pi] (h + r^2)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've found a bug! I think different parts of Mathematica deal with `Tube` differently.

Note that `DiscretizeRegion` thinks `Tube` is degenerate: evaluate `DiscretizeRegion[Tube[]]` for an error message. This suggests to me the reason for the mixing of areas and lengths in the `Area` output—some kind of degeneracy. (By the way, it's not only `Area` that doesn't work—`Area`'s functionality likely comes through `RegionMeasure`, and that gives the same bizarre result.)

**A workaround:** However, `RegionMember` seems to work "as expected" and produce a good tube. Thus we can use this in conjunction with `ImplicitRegion` to make our own tube (with memoization as long as there are no messages, so we don't always have to recompute; not sure this actually needs it, though, as it seems pretty fast):

```
fixedTube[args___] := 
 Module[{tube},
   (fixedTube[args] = tube) /;
    Check[(tube = 
      ImplicitRegion[RegionMember[Tube[args], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]); True, 
      False]]
```

(See `DiscretizeRegion @ fixedTube[]` to be convinced that this works.)

Note that this produces a filled-in 3D tube (as opposed to just its surface). This seems different than the region Mathematica considers `Tube[]` to refer to by itself!

```
RegionDimension[fixedTube[]] (* 3 *)

RegionDimension[Tube[]]      (* 2 *)
```

This is weird, because `ImplicitRegion` should essentially be the inverse of `RegionMember`. So I suspect this is a bug, and that Mathematica is mistakenly treating `Tube` one way in some part of its code but not in another.

Comment: (+1) Have you reported this to the support?

Comment: `DiscretizeGraphics` also [thinks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261087/280) that `Tube[]` is a 2D region.

Comment: `ImplicitRegion` gives a full region because `RegionMember` considers interior points part of the region, e.g., `RegionMember[Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1/2], {0, 0, 0}]` returns `True`. As you note, inconsistent definition among different region functions.

Answer (score 1):

The original bug is fixed in version 13.0.1:

```
Simplify[Area[Tube[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]], h > 0]
```

> ```
> 4 Pi r (h + r)
> ```

Which equals to

```
Simplify[Area[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]] + 2 h Perimeter[Disk[{0, 0}, r]]]
```

> ```
> 4 Pi r (h + r)
> ```

And also equals to

```
Simplify[SurfaceArea[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -h}, {0, 0, h}}, r]] - 2 Area[Disk[{0, 0}, r]] + 
  Area[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]], h > 0]
```

> ```
> 4 Pi r (h + r)
> ```